Is Ravana called "Arya" in Ramayana?
So says Ami Ganatra
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1re-mNXu10
But Ravana also says to Sita that if she wouldn't consent to him, he will send her to the kitchen to be cooked and eaten.
This doesn't seem consistent with "Arya" either by birth or conduct.

After the death of Ravana, wives of Ravana addresses him as Arya Putra:

उत्तरेण विनिष्क्रम्य द्वारेण सह राक्षसैः | प्रविश्यायोधनं घोरं
विचिन्वन्त्यो हतं पतिम् || ६-११०-३
आर्यपुत्रेति वादिन्यो हा नाथेति च सर्वशः | परिपेतुः कबन्धाङ्कां महीं शोणितकर्दमाम् || ६-११०-४
Translation:
Issuing out of the northern gate along with demons and penetrating
into the terrific battle-field, searching for their husband, who had
been killed and crying out, "Ah my lord! Ah my husband!" they all
ran hither and thither on the ground which was covered with headless
trunks and rendered muddy with blood."
Valmiki Ramayana 6.110.3-4

